# Expression for $k_\mathrm{eq}$, the wavenumber entering the horizon at matter-radiation equality

Tags: cosmology, perturbation-theory

For the past few days I have been busy with studying cosmology more specifically chapter 8 in the book by dodelson on modern cosmology. I have the following question concerning equation (8.70) which is the following
$$k_{eq} = a_{eq}H(a_{eq}) = \sqrt{2\Omega_m}H_0a_{eq}^{1/2},$$
where the subscript eq stand for matter-radiation equality. I do not get why the second equality holds. I think it looks somewhat like the Freedmann-Lemaitre equation which relates the Hubble parameter to the different densities ($\Omega$), however only the matter density appears whereas in the Freedmann-Lemaitre equation I do not see how I could eliminate the cosmological constant density.

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but it's possible that the equation is only meant to hold assuming $\Omega_\Lambda$ is negligible, which is a good approximation around the relatively high redshift of matter-radiation equality.

Comment: why could it be neglected? Also since $\Omega_r = \Omega_m$ at matter-radiation equality how can I get rid of the factor of $a^{-4}$ for radiation?

Comment: oh nevermind i know how to get rid of the $a^{-4}$ factor, however why I can neglect $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ is still unclear to me

Comment: Please consider changing your title as it is not even meaningful to those who have the book and does not describe at all the content of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$H(a_\mathrm{eq})=H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_\mathrm{m}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-3}+\Omega_\mathrm{r}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-4}+\Omega_\Lambda}.$$
But $\Omega_\mathrm{m}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-3}=\Omega_\mathrm{r}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-4}$ at matter-radiation equality, by definition: the matter density and radiation density are equal. Also $\Omega_\Lambda\simeq 0.69$, while $\Omega_\mathrm{m}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-3}=\Omega_\mathrm{r}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-4}\sim 10^{10}$. That is, matter and radiation totally dominate over dark energy at the time of matter-radiation equality. So we can neglect the dark energy. This leads to
$$H(a_\mathrm{eq})=H_0 \sqrt{2\Omega_\mathrm{m}a_\mathrm{eq}^{-3}}$$
and hence the expression in the book.